# How to use loop in json to xml plugin

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

I am using the 'jstoxml' plugin that is created by David Calhoun.

Link: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/jstoxml

I have a goal object that should be variable, because it's possible to have more goals, but I can't use a for loop. So my question, how to use a for loop which create multiple objects that is variable.

```
  var goalsXML = jstoxml.toXML({
  goal: [{
      _name: 'typename',
      _content: [{
        _name: 'tysource',
        _attrs: {
          sourcetype: 'test'
      }
  },
  {
      _name: 'tyvalue',
      _content: test.title
  }]
}
```

I have included two goals, so the result should:

```
<goal>
   ...
</goal>
<goal>
  ...
</goal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for using my library!  See this example: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/jstoxml#example-3-duplicate-tag-names

That should be the general structure you need.  So it'll look something like this:

```
jstoxml.toXML([
  {
    _name: 'typename',
    _content: {
      _name: 'tysource',
      _attrs: {
        sourcetype: 'test'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    _name: 'tyvalue',
    _content: 'title'
  }
])
```